# Antlr insists a token is missing although it appears to not be missing

Tags: antlr

Just giving Antlr a try and I'm running into an error I can't quite understand

```
grammar Input;

start   : cityLink*;
cityLink : CityName DASH CityName (NEWLINE | EOF);

CityName          : [A-Z] Word?;
Word              : [a-z]+;
DASH              : WS '-' WS -> skip;
WS                : ' '+ -> skip;
NEWLINE           : '\r'? '\n' -> skip;
```

I'm trying to parse

```
Chicago - Naperville
```

This seems like it should work, the ouput is correct-ish with the error message:

```
line 1:10 missing DASH at 'Naperville'
```

I'm pretty stuck on why I'd be getting this message, I keep reading the docs about maximal lexer matching rules, but I just can't seem to spot my problem here.  Any input would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've marked the `DASH` rule with `skip`, so `DASH` tokens won't show up in the token stream. If you want to be able to use `DASH` in your grammar, you should not be skipping it.

Comment: This was it exactly, I thought I was just suppressing the DASH from being in my CityLink as it was a worthless bit of data.  Thank you so much.